# Fetch ID in Post method response and ID is autogenerated

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Trying to fetch ID in response that is stored in database of Post request. In table ID is auto generated. tried one code but it is not working.
I am not passing ID in Json post. Please suggest how it will be done. Tried using list and stored the data is list1 variable but in that variable last data which is in Json that data is storing in the variable.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<DelegateTable> delegatetable)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ShowContext delegateContext = new ShowContext())
            {
                DelegateTable delegates = new DelegateTable();
                List<DelegateTable> list1 = new List<DelegateTable>();

                foreach (DelegateTable item in delegatetable)
                {

                    delegates.Salutation__c = item.Salutation__c;
                    delegates.First_Name__c = item.First_Name__c;
                    delegates.Last_Name__c = item.Last_Name__c;
                    delegates.Account_Name__c = item.Account_Name__c;
                    delegates.Contact_Email__c = item.Contact_Email__c;
                    delegates.Category__c = item.Category__c;
                    delegates.Conference_Type__c = item.Conference_Type__c;
                    delegates.Conference_Selection__c = item.Conference_Selection__c;
                    delegates.Payment_Status_Interface__c = item.Payment_Status_Interface__c;
                    delegates.Barcode__c = item.Barcode__c;
                    delegateContext.delegates.Add(delegates);

                    delegateContext.SaveChanges();
                    list1.Add(delegates);

                }

                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, list1);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString());
                return message;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

Json format that i am passing is below

```
 [
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "Registration__c",
      "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Registration__c/a3hD0000001kE8YIAU"
    },
    "Salutation__c": null,
    "First_Name__c": "Test",
    "Last_Name__c": "Test",
    "Account_Name__c": "Test",
    "Contact_Email__c": "Test@gmail.com",
    "Category__c": "Test",
    "Conference_Type__c": null,
    "Conference_Selection__c": null,
    "Payment_Statuss__c": null,
    "Barcode__c": "Test"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "Registration__c",
      "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Registration__c/a3hD0000001kEfOIAU"
    },
    "Salutation__c": "Mr.",
    "First_Name__c": "Demo",
    "Last_Name__c": "Demo",
    "Account_Name__c": "Demo",
    "Contact_Email__c": "Demo@yahoo.com",
    "Category__c": "Demo",
    "Conference_Type__c": null,
    "Conference_Selection__c": null,
    "Payment_Statuss__c": null,
    "Barcode__c": "Demo"
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can again query the Saved changes in DB after your do the delegateContext.SaveChanges(), for the ID which is generated, for the specified item and store them in the list of each variable and have it in your response query.
Hope I understood your question correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Tried below code to fetch ID from database but now problem is that it is fetching all data from database. I just want to display only that data which currently got inserted in database. Added this code in previous one.

```
 string query = "Select * from DelegateTable";

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    conn.Open();
                    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        DelegateTable newItem = new DelegateTable();
                        newItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
                        newItem.First_Name__c = dr["First_Name__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Last_Name__c = dr["Last_Name__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Account_Name__c = dr["Account_Name__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Contact_Email__c = dr["Contact_Email__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Category__c = dr["Category__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Barcode__c = dr["Barcode__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Conference_Type__c = dr["Conference_Type__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Conference_Selection__c = dr["Conference_Selection__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Payment_Status_Interface__c = dr["Payment_Status_Interface__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        list1.Add(newItem);
                    }
                        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, list1);
                        message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString());
                        return message;
```

Below is the modified code after adding above code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<DelegateTable> delegatetable)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ShowContext delegateContext = new ShowContext())
                {
                    DelegateTable delegates = new DelegateTable();
                    List<DelegateTable> list1 = new List<DelegateTable>();

                    foreach (DelegateTable item in delegatetable)
                    {

                        delegates.Salutation__c = item.Salutation__c;
                        delegates.First_Name__c = item.First_Name__c;
                        delegates.Last_Name__c = item.Last_Name__c;
                        delegates.Account_Name__c = item.Account_Name__c;
                        delegates.Contact_Email__c = item.Contact_Email__c;
                        delegates.Category__c = item.Category__c;
                        delegates.Conference_Type__c = item.Conference_Type__c;
                        delegates.Conference_Selection__c = item.Conference_Selection__c;
                        delegates.Payment_Status_Interface__c = item.Payment_Status_Interface__c;
                        delegates.Barcode__c = item.Barcode__c;
                        delegateContext.delegates.Add(delegates);

                        delegateContext.SaveChanges();

                    }

                    string query = "Select * from DelegateTable";

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    conn.Open();
                    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        DelegateTable newItem = new DelegateTable();
                        newItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
                        newItem.First_Name__c = dr["First_Name__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Last_Name__c = dr["Last_Name__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Account_Name__c = dr["Account_Name__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Contact_Email__c = dr["Contact_Email__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Category__c = dr["Category__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Barcode__c = dr["Barcode__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Conference_Type__c = dr["Conference_Type__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Conference_Selection__c = dr["Conference_Selection__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        newItem.Payment_Status_Interface__c = dr["Payment_Status_Interface__c"].ToString().Trim();
                        list1.Add(newItem);
                    }
                        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, list1);
                        message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString());
                        return message;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can anyone help for above issue